# Opposite of "dive deeper"

Tags: phrase-requests

- "Rise/Ascend shallower" doesn't have quite a nice ring to it.
- Optimally using two words!
- Also, I don't necessarily mean by swimming. One should be able to apply the phrase to both swimming creatures or submersibles.
- To be explicit, I don't want the phrase to mean "go to the surface". Just shallower.

Comment: Swim back towards the surface of the water!!

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, if I just want two words, "swim back" sounds a bit lacking (or is it just me?)

Comment: As the submarine captain shouts, *Surface! Surface!*

Comment: Resurface - sorry it's only one word.

Comment: Do you want to use it in a longer sentence or as an exclamation? As exclamations, I think "*Go shallower!*" (or "*Ascend!*") could match "*Dive deeper!*".

Comment: I wanted to use it as text in a button, in a visualisation/game. So shouldn't be too long, and no exclamation marks needed. I like ascend and rise, but I'm not sure if it's even ok to use them with shallower.

Comment: "Bubble up"????

Comment: "Rise higher" rather than "shallower"?

Comment: Bingo. Probably this.

Comment: antonym for **dive deeper** (used to mean studying a topic in depth) -- **back to (the) basics**

Comment: I've tried to edit out the false antonym element of this question, but it is still fatally flawed.  A very high-tech submersible might have the ability to dive deeper than its counterparts of earlier generations, but in terms of rising to the surface, well, a popsicle stick can do that. Sounds as though he's looking for a slogan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Ascend"](https://www.padi.com/scuba-diving/padi-courses/course-catalog/specialty-diver/peak-performance-diver/) is used within the diving community to mean "rise|swim upwards, towards the surface". It does not imply that you actually reach the surface.

> Excellent buoyancy control is what defines skilled scuba divers. You’ve seen them underwater. They glide effortlessly, use less air and *ascend*, descend or hover almost as if by thought.

*www.padi.com*

Answer (score 1):

The naval term for a boat travelling towards the surface is **ascend** or **rise**.

> Prior to rising to periscope depth, the *Greeneville* executes a series of turns.
> These data show the *Greeneville* ascending to an initial periscope depth...
>
> [National Transportation Safety Board](http://www.ntsb.gov/news/press-releases/Pages/USS_GreenevilleEhime_Maru_Collision_Update.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

if you are speaking figuratively, like "lets dive deeper into this problem",then to indicate lesser intensity there are terms like 'paddle in the kiddy pool', or a small start is 'get our feet wet'.  to indicate lessening of intensity after one has done the deep dive, but finds that one has bitten off more than one can chew, then might 'scale back', 'backpaddle', 'reverse gears' etc.